# Get set-cookie value from the response header angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, setcookie, response-headers

I am trying to get the `set-cookie` from `Response Headers`.

The reason of doing this is set-cookie is not setting cookie and showing the warning `This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url`. Attached is the screenshot

[image]

Now I thought to get the set-cookie value from Response Header by the following code
[image]

But it always returns `null` for `set-cookie` but return the value fo `expires`.

Please anyone can guide how to fix this issue or how can I get the value of `set-cookie` from Response Header.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: According to this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), states the following: "Browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the Set Cookie header, as required by the Fetch spec, which defines Set-Cookie as a forbidden response-header name that must be filtered out from any response exposed to frontend code."

Answer (score 0):

According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) `set-cookie` is a forbidden response header name. You cannot read it using browser-side JavaScript

> Browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the Set Cookie header, as required by the Fetch spec, which defines Set-Cookie as a forbidden response-header name that must be filtered out from any response exposed to frontend code.

Comment: Thanks @VVS, Please let me know how can I do that then Because this set-cookie is not setting a cookie in the browser due to user login is not workin. That's why I need to get the cookie or any solution that will set the cookie.

Comment: What is the domain on the backend and on the frontend? if they are different then you can try to have them on the same domain to see if that works.

Comment: Currently, it is on the localhost.

Comment: So are you confirming that they are different on both sides, the domain on frontend and backend differ? if so then you will get an invalid cookie as its different origin.

Comment: Can I change the domain on the front end? So that the domain on the frontend and backend would be the same.

Comment: Well as long as both domains match that should prevent the `invalid cookie` error. (I'm not sure about how you change it but it definitely needs to be the same)